# How to allow user to try a different email after failure in NodeJS PassportJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, passport.js

Currently I am checking whether or not a user has a certain domain name email address using the following code. Initially, when the google authentication window shows, there is no option for the user to change their email address if they are already logged into Chrome. When I log into similar sites with Google authentication, I seemingly recalled being allowed to add an email address, or something of that nature.

So, say that the user attempts to log on with a non-lsmsa.edu email address and it fails. Currently it displays a nasty error. How would I make it such that the user is allowed to attempt to re-login with a different email address.

```
if ( profile.emails[0].value.indexOf("lsmsa.edu") > -1 ) {

    var newUser = new User()

    newUser.google.id    = profile.id
    newUser.google.token = token
    newUser.google.name  = profile.displayName
    newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value

    newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err
        return done(null, newUser)
    })
}
else {
    done(new Error("Invalid Domain. Must use LSMSA email address."))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`hd` parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect%23hd-param). It makes sure that the user can only sign in with a proper email.

**EDIT:** This isn't a per-request option. If you want to use it with `passport-google-oauth`, edit your config to be like this:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://www.example.com/auth/google/return',
    realm: 'http://www.example.com/',
    // Add this
    hd: 'example.com'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    // Blah Blah Blah, Blow up Pluto, Milk Cows, Eat Chocolate, Etc.
  }
));
```

**EDIT:** If for some reason you ***have*** to have them login again, instead of using `hd`, just destroy the session (`req.session.destroy();`), then redirect them to your authentication url (ie. `/auth/google`). However, using `hd` will be a much nicer user experience.

Comment: I am doing that in the code that I already have shown, simply in a different way. I want to redirect them to try again somehow after the error, if they enter an email with an incorrect domain name.

Comment: @Connorelsea with that option, they can't sign in with a wrong email. If you need them to sign in again, just redirect as normal.

Comment: I don't think I have permission to access the hd parameter. It is saying the _json.hd is null. Do I need to add anything to my Google Developer thing?

Comment: @Connorelsea: No, it's not a response param. If your domain was "example.com", then in your passport options, put `hd: "example.com",`.

Comment: Thank you SO much for the help. I really, really appreciate it. Truly. How would I check the hd value before the session is created and then not create the session at all if their email is wrong. Then I want to redirect them to the auth again to give them a chance to change emails.

Comment: The point is I am making this in an academic setting and only allowing student or faculty emails. But someone may be logged in on their personal email, attempt to log in, and then be stuck in a loop of forever being unable to log in. I think the req.session.destroy() thing would work, but you seem to be implying there is a more elegant way. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Connorelsea: Please don't be rude with me. If you look at my edited answer, you pass it as an option to passport when you set it up. Then it sends it to Google with the authorization request, ***and Google will not let you sign in with an invalid email***.

Comment: I am sorry if it came off as rude. I was trying to be as thankful as possible but I could see how it as seemingly sarcastic haha. I will message you on reddit. I feel bad now that you thought I was trying to be rude. Sorry dude.

Comment: No problem. I do that all the time.